# Line in graph is backwards

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting two lines, however the green line is starting from the right side of the graph, I would like both lines to start from the left. Thank you

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(totalReturnComp["S&P compounded growth"], linewidth=2, color='b') 
ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(CompoundGrowth_10M["10M Equal Weight"], linewidth=2, color='g')
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()

plt.title('10 Month Incremental Weight vs S&P Index')
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnU86.png)

Data used:

[10M Equal weight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8ve0.png)
[SnP compounded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s06tE.png)

Comment: If you show part of the data totalReturnComp["S&P compounded growth"], CompoundGrowth_10M["10M Equal Weight"]. Then maybe I can help you.

Comment: You are inverting the xaxis of ax2, but not ax1.

Comment: Actually, he is inverting both xaxis of ax1 and ax2, as they are twin.